# Axios cancelToken, make cancelled request fail silently

Tags: javascript, reactjs, request, axios, react-hook-form

I am creating an input form that verifies an account number onChange, using `react-hook-form`

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (account_number.length >= 6) {
      verifyAccountNumber();
    }
    return () => source.cancel('Request canceled!');
  }, [account_number, bank_code, verifyAccountNumber]);
```

the `verifyAccountNumber` function runs when `account_number` and `bank_code` state changes.

Here is the actual function

```
const verifyAccountNumber = useCallback(async () => {
    setAccountLoading(true);
    setAccountError({ status: false, serverError: false });
    try {
      const account = await restAPI.get(
        `/misc/verify-account/${account_number}/${bank_code}`,
        { cancelToken: token }
      );
      setAccount(account.data.data.data.account_name);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      if (!axios.isCancel(err)) {
        setAccountError({
          status: true,
          serverError: err.response.data.serverError,
        });
      }
    }
    setAccountLoading(false);
  }, [account_number, bank_code]);
```

is there a way of preventing the try catch block from catching a cancelled request as an error? because its messing up my UI/UX

Comment: If you want to prevent catching cancelled request errors, you have to rethrow it in your case. `if (axios.isCancel(err)) { throw err } else { setAccountError(...) }`

Comment: thanks, but when I just tried that, it kept on logging Uncaught (in promise) to the console, indefinitely

Comment: @JosefWittmann neve rmind it works fine thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent catching cancellation errors, you have to rethrow it in your case.

```js
if (axios.isCancel(err)) { 
    throw err 
} else { 
    setAccountError(...) 
}
```

*(Answer from comments to document this issue as resolved)*